# How to solve $\frac12 \sec^2 \frac x2 = 1$ under restricted domain?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

solve:

$$\frac12 \sec^2 \left(\frac x2\right) = 1$$ and domain $x: (-\pi,\pi) \cup (\pi,3\pi)$.

- sec^2 (x/2) = 2
- sec^2 (x/2) can be re-written as tan(x/2)^2 + 1, therefore
- tan^2(x/2) + 1 = 2
- tan^2(x/2) = 1
- tan(x/2) = 1
- x/2 = pi/4, 5pi/4, -pi/4 these fit in the domain
- x = pi/2, 5pi/2, -pi/2

the solution says 3pi/2 and as another angle for x.... the reference angle is then 3pi/4 but how is this possible? tan(pi/4) is negative for tan(3pi/4)

can someone please explain - also, is my method correct?

Comment: Please use $LaTeX$ using `$...$` in your equation. For examples `$\pi$`, `$\tan x$`, and `$\frac{1}{2}$` become $\pi$, $\tan x$,and $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: You might find [this MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) helpful :)

Comment: Take a look my edit and you edit the rest using my example.

Comment: $whatever^2=1$ doesn't mean $whatever$ has to be $1$.

Comment: plus/minus 1 ? then solve .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is when you conclude $$tan^2(x/2) = 1 \implies \tan(x/2) = 1$$

What you *can* conclude is that $$\tan^2(x/2) = 1 \implies \tan (x/2) = \pm 1$$

So you need also to consider which value(s) of $x$ (in the domain) satisfy $\tan(x/2) = -1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac12 \sec^2 \left(\frac x2\right) = 1 \Rightarrow \frac12 \frac{1}{\cos^2 \left(\frac x2\right)} = 1 \Rightarrow \frac12 =\cos^2 \left(\frac x2\right) \Rightarrow \cos \left(\frac x2\right)= \pm \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$$